# Circuit to control a motor using relays

Tags: relay, esp8266

I want to do an automatic door for our chicken coop. The battery part is done (a small solar panel, an old car battery and a solar charger). The issue is with the door itself. I have a door actuator motor running at 12V and a 4 relay board using ESP8266 (https://www.banggood.com/AC-or-DC-Power-Supply-ESP8266-WIFI-Four-way-Relay-Module-ESP-12F-Development-Board-Secondary-Development-p-1794113.html?cur_warehouse=CN).

As far as I understand, in theory, [image]

I can do that to control direction (open/close) of the door. Right?

Will it work in practice? I mean ... I'm a software developer as a job and I understand race-condition, what I'm afraid of .. is that the relays won't switch exactly in the same time and, in some cases, it will short the car battery. Am I wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no way this arrangement can short the car battery - only the motor. Check out all the possible combinations. But you should add a fuse to your circuit anyway, so that if you accidentally short the battery, the fuse will pop and nothing else will pop.

Comment: Are you going to add any safety mechanism or electric eye circuity that would prevent your chickens from getting stuck in the closing door? [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: Good question @Nedd . The motor is actually pulling up a textile cord and the door is quite low weight (I made it out of plywood that goes on a wooden rail), something like https://i.ytimg.com/vi/J9-nWuMv2m0/maxresdefault.jpg but instead of horizontal it is on the vertical axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect the relays as drawn in your circuit, then there is no chance of shorting the car battery. Since the relays won't switch at identical times, you may have very short time periods where the current flow is not as you expect, but all the paths for the current go through the motor, meaning that there are no combinations of relay states that result in shorting the battery.

Back emf is something you may need to worry about though, so you should look into that.

Comment: Thank you. Considering the setup, and the current going both ways (due to reversing the flow) .. how can the back emf be solved?

Comment: One way is to use a bidirectional TVS diode in parallel with the motor - this is a type of diode where the breakdown voltage is controlled. This means that the diode will not let any current through in either direction until the voltage goes over a defined maximum, and then it will conduct until the voltage goes below that level. There are thousands of options, but something like this would work  if your max voltage is 12V (https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/littelfuse-inc/SA15CA/407646)

Comment: If your voltage is above 12V (a 12V lead acid battery can go up to 14V or so) then you would want one with a higher standoff voltage.